# Moving From One textfield to Another during Next Button click in Virtual Keyboard

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

So i have Two Text Box , lets say , TextBox1 and TwoBox2 .
On Viewdidload TextBox1 i am using

```
 [self.TextBox1 becomeFirstResponder];
```

Now how to move the Cursor to TextBox2 ,when i press Next Button in Virtual Keyboard

Comment: Do you mean UITextField or UITextView?  ("Text Box" isn't a real iOS thing.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Cocoa for Mac OS X you have the next responder chain, where you can ask the text field what control should have focus next. This is what makes tabbing between text fields work. But since iPhone do not have a key board, only touch, this concept has not survived the transition to Cocoa Touch.

This can be easily done anyway, with two assumptions:

All "tabbable" UITextFields are on the same parent view.
Their "tab-order" is defined by the tag property.
Assuming this you can override textFieldShouldReturn: as this:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*)textField;
{
 NSInteger nextTag = textField.tag + 1;
  // Try to find next responder
 UIResponder* nextResponder = [textField.superview viewWithTag:nextTag];
 if (nextResponder) {
  // Found next responder, so set it.
  [nextResponder becomeFirstResponder];
 } else {
 // Not found, so remove keyboard.
  [textField resignFirstResponder];
 }
 return NO; // We do not want UITextField to insert line-breaks.
 }
```

Add some more code, and the assumptions can be ignored as well.

Answer (score 3):

In the callback for Next Button, use,

```
 [self.TextBox2 becomeFirstResponder];
```

Easy!

Comment: i mean what event Type did i select in IBAction of TextBox1